# Custom CSS security

Tags: css, security

I'm doing work on a website, and a user can create a custom CSS stylesheet. I understand that there will always be a danger in this, but is there any way that I could make my validation more secure? I'm using this:

```
$customCSS = $_POST["submittedCustomCSS"]; //put user's submitted stylesheet into variable
$customCSS = htmlspecialchars($customCSS); //hopefully validate it?
file_put_contents("../custom.css", $customCSS); //save user's stylesheet
```

The page the custom CSS is displayed on is PHP-enabled, and the CSS is shown through `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $postID; ?>/custom.css">`
Is there any way to make this more secure? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: security.stackexchange.com might be a better forum for this question.

Comment: @Roopendra: What the hell? How was that an improvement of formatting?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You can check revision. It was more readable then current version.

Comment: @Roopendra: Sorry, I don't see how that could have possibly made it more readable - unless you use a proportional-width font with your code editor instead of a fixed-width font like the rest of us do. It's still an incorrect edit anyway; [blockquotes](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) and [code blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) are not the same thing - they are not supposed to be interchangeable. If it's code, it goes into a code block. Not a blockquote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> htmlspecialchars($customCSS); //hopefully validate it?
> ```

No, this is not sufficient.  This may stop the CSS from escaping a `</style>` element in which it is embedded, but does nothing to prevent the CSS from styling arbitrary elements on the page, or from loading custom fonts or from abusing other problematic features of CSS whose security implications are still poorly understood.

---

If a custom stylesheet can be applied to any page that it's author cannot access, then you need to be significantly more strict than this.  There are ways that custom stylesheets can be exploited to steal data like Credit-Card numbers or XSRF tokens that don't need to run JS.

For example, if one user can elect to use another user's custom stylesheet, then that could lead to a security vulnerability, and you should not require users to be able to read and vet a CSS file to use features of your site safely.

["Scriptless Attacks – Stealing the Pie Without Touching the Sill"](http://www.nds.rub.de/media/emma/veroeffentlichungen/2012/08/16/scriptlessAttacks-ccs2012.pdf) explains some of the ways injected CSS can be problematic:

> We show that CSS markup, which is traditionally considered to be only
>   used for decoration/display purposes, actually enables an
>   attacker to perform malicious activities.
>
> ...
>
> We introduce several novel attacks that we call
>   scriptless attacks, as an attacker can obtain the credit card
>   number by injecting markup to this page without relying on
>   any kind of (JavaScript) code execution.
>
> ...
>
> Neither of the discussed attacks depends on user interaction
>   on the victim’s part, but uses a mix of benign HTML, CSS
>   and Web Open Font Format (WOFF [23]) features combined
>   with a HTTP-request-based side channel to measure and ex-
>   ﬁltrate almost arbitrary data displayed on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Because Microsoft added CSS expressions as a proprietary extension to Internet Explorer, handling untrusted CSS securely is more complex than simply encoding it correctly.  To do this properly you need to parse the CSS then only output things matching a whitelist.  Unless you do this, it's trivial to inject JavaScript into the page for Internet Explorer visitors.

An alternative approach would be to only accept valid CSS, however I'd be concerned that Microsoft might try to sneak something in inside comments or something like they did with HTML.